# Show saved messages from the database MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I created a chat on spring boot. Where several people can correspond. So I created a database and there I store all messages from users. So I want, if a new user enters the chat, then he should see only the last 10 messages. The problem is that the program does not take the last 10 messages from the database, it takes them from the server, this is not correct. I want him to take the last 10 messages from the database.

My code

Rest Controller

```
@SpringComponent
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {
    private List<Message> store;

    public RestController() {
        store = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @PutMapping("/api/save")
    public void saveMessage(@RequestBody String chatMessage) {
        store.add(new Gson().fromJson(chatMessage, Message.class));

        if (store.size() > 10)
            store.remove(0);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/last")
    public String getLasts() {
        return new Gson().toJson(store);
    }
}
```

Message class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chatMessages")
public class Message {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String fromV;
  private String messageV;
  private Timestamp time;

  public Timestamp getTime() {
    return time;
  }

  public void setTime(Timestamp time) {
    this.time = time;
  }

  public Message() { }

  public String getFromV() {
    return fromV;
  }

  public void setFromV(String fromV) {
    this.fromV = fromV;
  }

  public String getMessageV() {
    return messageV;
  }

  public void setMessageV(String messageV) {
    this.messageV = messageV;
  }

  public Message(String from, String message) {
    this.fromV = from;
    this.messageV = message;
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFrom() {
    return fromV;
  }

  public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.fromV = from;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return messageV;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.messageV = message;
  }
}
```

MessageRepository

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
}
```

MessageService

```
public interface MessageService {
    void add(Message message);

    List<Message> getAllMessages();
}
```

MessageServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    private final MessageRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MessageServiceImpl(MessageRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Message message) {
        message.setTime(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        repository.saveAndFlush(message);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

MessageList

```
 public MessageList() {
    addClassName("message-list");
  }

  @Override
  public void add(Component... components) {
    super.add(components);


    components[components.length-1]
        .getElement()
        .callFunction("scrollIntoView");
  }
}
```

Application Controller

```
server.port=8080
# This is a workaround for https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/381
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = false

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chat?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: try to get last 10 messages in RestController.getLasts() instead of whole store object

Comment: You can bring the code

Comment: you can use Page and Pageable so add you api @ApiParam Pageable pageable and your repository should been  public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
} and just call him in your rest         Page<YourClass> page = pkoCategoryRequirementRepository.findAll(pageable);

Comment: getLasts() {return new Gson().toJson(store.subList(Math.max(store.size() - 10, 0), store.size()));}

Comment: This is not correct((

Comment: Can you please explain, why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: need to pull messages from the database

Answer (score 0):

To be frankly,i don't understand the purpose of the object store in your controller. If you want to query the last 10 messages.You can just implement a method in repository and invoke it in your controller.

**MessageRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
  List<Message> findTop10ByOrderByTimeDesc();
}
```